# Isolated scope is not working in angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I have understanding the concept of isolated scope.

I am fine with theoretical side. I have executing isolated scope on code but i am not getting clear idea about this.

This is my custom directive

```
<users mystats="stats"></users>
```

I have assigning value from parent controller.

and this is my custom directive

```
directive.restrict = "E";
    directive.templateUrl = "templates/partials/users_stats.html";
    directive.scope = {
        stats:'=mystats'
    }
directive.controller = "userStatsCtrl";
```

and custom directive's controller is

```
app.controller("userStatsCtrl", function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.$watchCollection ('stats', function(newValue) {
      if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
         console.log($scope)
      }
    });
})
```

Everything is working upto this. Here, i am trying to integrated isolated scope concept. but i am not getting idea about how to integrate on this code

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to integrate isolated scope concept"? What are you trying to do? Is the property on the parent controller's scope called `stats`?

Comment: Here im watching scope object. Instead of this, i need to get updation on change of stats

Comment: And. Isolated defines, if we change the child object, parent scope will not affect. I dont need to use  watch or  scope. If stats get update, i need to do perform on custom directive's controller

Comment: If you need to run code whenever the parent `stats` object changes, without the parent having to "tell" your directive about the change, then the only way to do so is to use a `$watch()` of some sort.

Comment: If you bind an object (or array) on the isolate scope, then the object will be the same on the parent and isolate scopes, and mutating it in either place will affect the other. Only primitives that are one-way bound on the isolate scope are completely disconnected from the parent.

Comment: yes. but watching scope is reducing performance. Thats y, i am looking alternative way to listen parent changes from directive

Comment: How to bind the isolated scope on this code